# copy function does not recognize image on another canvas in p5js

Tags: javascript, processing, p5.js

I'm trying to make 'slitscan' effects.
I set 2 canvases. One on the right is for source image, and another is for scan effect.
When i tried it with text function it works perfectly, however with an image, the copy function gives me an error message.

[image: the error message]

This is the p5 code I wrote

```
let a1, a2;
let cv1, cv2;
let dy = 0;

let s1 = function(p) {
  p.setup = () => {
    cv1 = p.createCanvas(300, 300);
    p.background(150);
    cv1.position(0, 0);
  }

  p.draw = () => {
    p.copy(cv2, 0, dy, 400, 1, 0, dy, 400, 1);
    
    if (dy > cv2.height) {
      dy = 0;
    } else {
      dy += 1;
    } 
  }
}
a1 = new p5(s1);

let s2 = function(p) {
  let img;

  p.preload = () => {
    img = p.loadImage('https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/635910989498724356/uY4bc8q2.jpg');
  }

  p.setup = () => {
    cv2 = p.createCanvas(300, 300);
    cv2.position(300, 0);
  }

  p.draw = () => {
    p.background(30);
    p.imageMode(p.CENTER);
    p.image(img, p.mouseX, p.mouseY);
  }
}
a2 = new p5(s2);
```

In addition, if you have a better idea to make multi-canvas or any suggestion about my code, please leave a comment.
Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `s1` sketch, you try to do stuff with the canvas `cv2`. Yet this canvas is only created later in your sketch.

To fix it, just change the order of your two sketches, i.e., call `a1 = new p5(s1);` after `a2 = new p5(s2);` (it doesn't matter when you define `s1` and `s2`, only when you instantiate them).

See, for example, this p5 editor [sketch](https://editor.p5js.org/janmaltel/sketches/Dai42D5_S).